# Highcharts stock control range when rangeSelector hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

how can one control the range selected on the occurrence of an event (e.g. a button gets clicked or the page loads) in Highstock, when rangeSelector is hidden.

The [API](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#rangeSelector) specifies that to hide the rangeSelector, one sets `rangeSelector : {enabled: false}`, but this not only hides the rangeSelector, but disables the user control of it completely. In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/enabled/), you can see the effect disabling the rangeSelector has.

Is there a way to control the range with the rangeSelector disabled? Or is there a way to hide the rangeSelector, but keep it enabled, so that the controls associated with it still work.

**Background info:**

I want to be able to make my own set of controls to control the range out of HTML/CSS and position them differently, as I dislike the aesthetics of the current controls.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not working when rangeSelector is disabled?

Comment: If you see here http://jsfiddle.net/Pffxt/, 'selected' does not work. I am trying to find a way to select a specific range.

Comment: Hi, did you solved this? I stucked on this too.

Comment: This answer does what we're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802472/how-to-hide-show-scrollbar-and-range-selector-of-highcharts-on-button-click

Answer (score 2):

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
})

chart.rangeSelector.destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks - that works perfectly, except when controlling the range at the bottom now, the mouse gets bound and does not get released on mouse up: http://jsfiddle.net/Pffxt/2/